# How can I get a symbolic solution to my equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve or somehow reduce my equation for $T$ as a function of $m_{be}$, but I am getting the response

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available

Here is my equation:

$$\frac{e^{-m_{be}/T}}{1+e^{-2\Delta/T}} m_{sm}^3 \frac{1}{m_{be}^{3/2}}\sqrt{\frac{\Delta}{m_{be}}} T^{1/2}== 8 m_{be}^2+24 m_{be} T+30 T^2 $$

Could anyone please help me to find the T dependency on $m_{be}$?

Comment: there is no code, I just use solve command. I don’t have any code for that

Comment: Could make available the `Solve` command you have?

Comment: This equation is transcendental, so you are not likely to be able to obtain an expression for $T$ using algebraic method.s

Comment: I think you are most likely to gain an insight by considering approximate solutions.  You would probably need to have some idea of the relative magnitude of your constants and variables to make the approximations.

Comment: @mikado yeah basically I ended up using some approximation on my other variables.